# comment a line using search pattern and insert new line shell script

Tags: bash, shell, perl, awk, sed

I am trying to comment a line in a file using search pattern, and then insert new line next to it.

```
search_variable=Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups
new_variable="wrapper.java.additional.47=-Dlog4j2.formatMsg=false"

cat testfile.txt    
wrapper.java.additional.47=-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
```

This one works, but trying to use variable to comment the line and

```
sed -i '/Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups/s/^/#/g' testfile.txt
```

output:

```
#wrapper.java.additional.47=-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
```

### Desired output

```
cat testfile.txt
#wrapper.java.additional.47=-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
wrapper.java.additional.47=-Dlog4j2.formatMsg=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
search_variable="Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups"
new_variable="wrapper.java.additional.47=-Dlog4j2.formatMsg=false"

sed -i "s/.*${search_variable}.*/#&\n${new_variable}/" testfile.txt
```

Output to testfile.txt:

```
#wrapper.java.additional.47=-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
wrapper.java.additional.47=-Dlog4j2.formatMsg=false
```

For the meaning of `&` see [using sed with ampersand (&)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296705/74329).

The curly brackets can also be omitted in this case.

This can also be helpful: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)